# Clearing Output Fields on JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a little problem using JSF and PrimeFaces. I have a form with two `<p:selectonemenu>`s and two `<h:outputText>`s. The contents of the first `<p:selectonemenu>` update the second, and the two `<h:outputText>`s are updated with the second `<p:selectonemenu>`. Both `<p:selectonemenu>`s are dependent on values on my backing bean. The issue is that I haven't been able to clear the `<h:outputText>`s when the FIRST `<p:selectonemenu>` changes it's value.

I tried using `<f:ajax>` with a listener to clear the contents of the current entity being displayed.

Here's the xhtml:

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.BailmentFamiliesLabel_bailmentFamCode}"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="bailmentFamilyCode" value="#{bailmentsController.selected.bailmentFamId}" required="false">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bailmentFamiliesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" var="famid"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" render="description price bailmentCode" listener="${bailmentsController.clearView(famid)}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.BailmentsLabel_bailmentCode}"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="bailmentCode" value="#{bailmentsController.selected}" required="false">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bailmentsController.itemsAvailableSelectOneByFamId}"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" render="globalForm" listener="#{bailmentsController.view(bailmentsController.selected.bailmentCode,bailmentsController.selected.bailmentFamId)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.Label_description}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bailmentsController.selected.description}" title="#{bundle.Title_description}" id="description"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.BailmentsLabel_purchasePriceMsj}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bailmentsController.selected.purchasePrice}" title="#{bundle.BailmentsTitle_purchasePrice}" id="price"/>
```

And the listener for the first `<p:selectonemenu>` on bailmentsController:

```
public void clearView(BailmentFamilies bf) {
    if (bf != null) {
        current = new Bailments();
        current.setBailmentFamId(bf);
    }
}
```

In my database, each Bailment is assigned a BailmentFamily, which is why I use a 2-step filter. The first `<p:selectonemenu>` lists all available BailmentFamilies, the second `<p:selectonemenu>` displays all available Bailments for the selected BailmentFamily. The `<h:outputText>`s display the information for the selected Bailment, which is why I need to clear them when BailmentFamily changes.

Can anyone suggest another course of action? As this has not proven productive. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you expecting the `<h:outputText>` to be ajax updated  when they've not been listed in the `render` attribute of the `<f:ajax/>` tag for the first select menu?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you expecting the `<h:outputText>` to be ajax updated  when they've not been listed in the `render` attribute of the `<f:ajax/>` tag for the first select menu? You need to

1. Assign `id` attributes to both `<h:outputText>`s

   ```
   <h:outputText id="text1" value="#{bundle.BailmentFamiliesLabel_bailmentFamCode}"/>
   <h:outputText id="text2" value="#{bundle.BailmentsLabel_bailmentCode}"/>
   ```
2. Reference the ids in the `<f:ajax/>`

   ```
   <f:ajax event="change" render="description text1 text2 price bailmentCode" listener="${bailmentsController.clearView(famid)}"/>
   ```

So far it would work. For an optimal/best-practice standpoint

1. Use `<p:ajax/>` instead. It's supposed to perform faster (because of the underlying jquery) and gives you access to other functionality

   ```
   <p:ajax update="description, text1, text2, price, bailmentCode" listener="${bailmentsController.clearView(famid)}"/>
   ```
2. Use EL notation (`#`) instead of JSTL(`$`)

   ```
   <p:ajax update="description, text1, text2, price, bailmentCode" listener="#{bailmentsController.clearView(famid)}"/>
   ```

Comment: I just solved the issue. I'll edit the question with the answer. I also forgot to add that everything is within a `<h:form id="globalForm>`, so all the components should be re-rendered. Thank you.

Comment: I assume that all the components provided in OP's question were inside `<h:form id="globalForm">` thus getting this error. Refer to OP's own answer for the solution of the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, now it's apparent. Without that bit of information, I was led to believe OP had cleared the value in the back, but the view failed to reflect the change

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the issue. Turns out I had to clear all the values within my entity. Silly perhaphs, but other developers could be stuck with this:

I edited my `clearView()` method. This was the code that worked:

```
public void clearView(BailmentFamilies bf) {
    if (bf != null) {
        // Create a new empty object to recieve the new BailmentFamily
        current = new Bailments();
        current.setBailmentFamId(bf); // This property has to be kept. 
        // I pass it as parameter and reassigned it to the current entity. 
        // Otherwise, the <p:selectonemenu> will clear upon rendering because of the new call above.
    }

    // Set ALL displayed properties to null
    current.setBailmentCode(null);
    current.setDescription(null);
    current.setPurchasePrice(null);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: +1, please endeavour to include relevant bits of info in your question in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ,

```
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset()" />
```

This will reset the form values but not the backing bean , so this approach wouldn't be safe if u were using form data from an actionListener/action outside the form.